# Wildfly Spring Arquillian - WAR getting deployed and undeployed with no exception

Tags: wildfly, jboss-arquillian

I am working on a project, where in I am trying to use Arquillian for integration testing. Our project is using Spring 4, Hibernate and we are trying to integrate it with Arquillian.
I was not able to find a suitable sample project explaining the use Arquillium Spring Extension in this link https://github.com/arquillian/arquillian-showcase/tree/master/spring
Most of the example involve testing business logic by creating JAR.
In this link https://github.com/arquillian/arquillian-extension-spring I found how to use Arquillian Spring Extension for testing web apps but not an example.

So here is what I am trying to do.
I have web archive generated for the project and it is getting deployed successfully on Wildfly without any issues or errors and we are able to access our webpage.

We added arquillian configuration for project, Initially we just plan to inject entity manager and perform the testing of DAO access layer. But we thought that we have completely deployable WAR , so lets setup arquillian for entire testing and not for just DAO layer. Hence we decided to configure the same.

Now I am not creating entire WAR again , but using the exisiting one with no change in any config file . (I know persistence-ds should be changed and used accordingly, but that can be done later using maven). So currently all my config files (applicationContext, beans.xml, hibernate.xml, web.xml, mappings.xml ... etc ) are all same as used in DEV env.

Can someone please help me out here, Also currently in Test case u won't see much testing logic, For time being I am just trying to inject entity manager and DAO layer

Next Options I can try are,
Not to use war directly but to create one using ShrinkWrap by adding packages and dependencies and so on.... I don't know if this is really necessary.
Other option, I can separate out logic code from view and create a JAR and then use @SpringConfiguration , and see if it works.
Or drop Spring Extension and use plain CDI and see if it works, but when it will come to Spring MVC testing I might have to solve this issue.

Comment: 2. POM.xml
https://gist.github.com/shrikanthavale/8cd19f2a6c3be8cc44be
3. Test Case
https://gist.github.com/shrikanthavale/b72e8c8348354db4d0c3

Comment: 1. Error,  (Maven -X) , sysout of WebArchive Structure  -
https://gist.github.com/shrikanthavale/ad4cc4015c53c98b64a2   Config Files - Web.xml, ApplicationContext.xml, hibernate,xml, beans.xml, faces-config, mvc-dispatcherservlet, mappings.xml
https://gist.github.com/shrikanthavale/273890d1cf844f28adc9

Comment: I was able to fix the issue of ArquillianServletRunner, by modifying the web.xml to 3.0 from 2.5 , not the deployment and server logs are clean ,but still no injection

Comment: What I see in log is BeanMangaer Not found, update the logs again. But beans.xml is present in web-inf folder. Test Case
https://gist.github.com/shrikanthavale/b72e8c8348354db4d0c3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is detailed answers and issues I faced, if it helps somebody

First I used to get Arquillian Servlet Runner not found,
I realized the issue was in web.xml

From Servlet 3.0 , web.xml has feature of metadata-complete="true", now this feature improves server startup time (Wildfly in my case) , but what it also does in Arquillian is ArquillianServletRunner which is servlet goes undetected.

And I was exactly the same WAR as I was using for development, and hence the problem.

What I had to do was just create a duplicate web.xml with metadata-complete = false and put in src/test/resources and update my development war and use it for arquillian.

Now Second issue, it was a mistake from my side, As we were using Spring container, we had removed Weld subsystem from standalone.xml of server.

But then when I added weld container back , beans started getting injected with @Inject annotation.

But I wanted my testing enviornment to be exact same as development enviornment, so I added proper arquillian spring dependencies and again removed weld container and it was still working.

So here is my update pom.xml and arquillian.xml.

https://gist.github.com/shrikanthavale/ec96736e32df8b6985bb
https://gist.github.com/shrikanthavale/8cd19f2a6c3be8cc44be